# glGetUniformfv for uniform variables declared as arrays

Tags: c++, opengl

For [glGetUniformfv](https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man2/xhtml/glGetUniform.xml), documentation states that "*To query values stored in uniform variables declared as arrays, call glGetUniform for each element of the array*"

Any example/hint on how to do that ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All you need to know to make this work is that uniform array locations are assigned sequentially beginning with `arrayname[0]`.

For each additional index, you can add **1** to this location. So if you wanted to get the value of `arrayname[21]`, you would find the location of `arrayname[0]` and then add **21** to that.

#### Consider the following pseudo-code:

```
GLint arrayname_0  = glGetUniformLocation (program, "arrayname[0]");
GLint arrayname_21 = glGetUniformLocation (program, "arrayname[21]");

assert (arrayname_0 + 21 == arrayname_21);
```

You could query the location of the 21<sup>st</sup> element of `arrayname` the hard way, or you could take advantage of the property mentioned earlier. In any case, if you want to get the value of specific element in a uniform array, this location is the one you need to pass.